Postgres Join base table with other tables and show all records without duplicate
I have three tables:
Base table:



parent_id
parent_name
location




P1
Mr. Smith
New York



Child table:



s_id
child_name
parent_id




C1
Jane
P1


C2
John
P1



School table:



school_id
school_name
parent_id




S1
Harvard
P1


S2
Princeton
P1



With this postgresql select statement
SELECT 
  a.parent_id, a.parent_name,a.location,
  b.c_id, b.child_name,
  c.school_id, c.school_name
FROM base a
LEFT JOIN child b ON a.parent_id = b.parent_id
LEFT JOIN school c ON a.parent_id = c.parent_id;

I get 4 records:



parent_id
parent_name
location
s_id
child_name
school_id
school_name




P1
Mr. Smith
New York
C1
Jane
S1
Harvard


P1
Mr. Smith
New York
C1
Jane
S2
Princeton


P1
Mr. Smith
New York
C2
John
S1
Harvard


P1
Mr. Smith
New York
C2
John
S2
Princeton



My issue is that I need to join 6 more tables to the base table but somehow each left join creates 2 additional rows.
My goal is to show all the data in all the tables linking to base table. I understand if the 3 table(courses) which might have 3 records with parent_id field to also join to the base data and show 3 records.
I want to see an output with 3 rows where b.c_id,b.child_name,c.school_id,c.school_name will have null values for the 3rd row because they only have 2 records each and courses have 3 records.
This is the output I was hoping to see



parent_id
parent_name
location
s_id
child_name
school_id
school_name
course_id
course_name




P1
Mr. Smith
New York
C1
Jane
S1
Harvard
C1
Maths


P1
Mr. Smith
New York
C2
John
S2
Princeton
C2
Science


P1
Mr. Smith
New York
null
null
null
null
C3
Music



thanks

Please repost your desired output as formatted text. See Senseful Solutions for good way to format output. Then update your question by placing the result between lines containing only ```.

Hi  - in the “output I was hoping to see” you have C2 Jane which I assume should be C2 John? Why/how are you assigning C1 to Harvard and C2 to Princeton when there is no such relationship in your source data? Why/how are you generating the last row with nulls - how does that relate to your source data?

@NickW you are correct, my mistake C2 is John. Maybe my thinking is wrong, I want all the child, school and course records to join with the base table. The last row with nulls means child and school have 2 records each and course has 3 records. I need to join 6 or more tables to the base table.

According to you data, both Jane and John go Harvard and Princeton. Drop parent_id in School table, but add School_id to Child table to be able to set in which school a child goes.

Please add a few rows of sample data of one of the "6 more tables" you want to join, and the expected result.

The reason for your multiplication of resulting rows is lack of join connection between school and child. The way you have it now both of the children are joined to both of the schools resulting with 4 rows (2 children x 2 schools).
To get 2 rows it is a must to define who is a student of which school. To do so you should have an additional column in school table (child_id) that will define the child as a student of the school:
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table base ( parent_id Varchar(8), parent_name Varchar(32), location Varchar(32) ); 
Insert Into base Values( 'P1', 'Mr. Smith', 'New York' );
--
Create Table child ( child_id Varchar(8), child_name Varchar(32), parent_id Varchar(8) ); 
Insert Into child Values( 'C1', 'Jane', 'P1' ), 
                        ( 'C2', 'John', 'P1' ); 
--                      
Create Table school ( school_id Varchar(8), school_name Varchar(32),
                      parent_id Varchar(8), child_id Varchar(8) ); 
Insert Into school Values( 'S1', 'Harvard', 'P1', 'C1' ), 
                         ( 'S2', 'Princeton', 'P1', 'C2' );
--
Create Table course ( course_id Varchar(8), course_name Varchar(32),
                      parent_id Varchar(8), child_id Varchar(8) ); 
Insert Into course Values( 'CRS1', 'Math', 'P1', 'C1' ), 
                         ( 'CRS2', 'Science', 'P1', 'C2' ), 
                         ( 'CRS3', 'Music', 'P1', 'C0' );

Now you can join the data and have no duplicate rows.
--    M a i n    S Q L :   (Option 1.) 
Select      b.parent_id, b.parent_name, b.location,  
            c.child_id, c.child_name,
            s.school_id, s.school_name, 
            crs.course_id, crs.course_name
From        base b
Left Join   child c ON( c.parent_id = b.parent_id )
Left Join   school s ON( s.parent_id = c.parent_id And 
                         s.child_id = c.child_id)
Left Join   course crs ON( crs.parent_id = b.parent_id And 
                           crs.child_id = c.child_id );

/*      R e s u l t :
PARENT_ID   PARENT_NAME LOCATION    CHILD_ID    CHILD_NAME  SCHOOL_ID   SCHOOL_NAME COURSE_ID   COURSE_NAME
---------   ----------- ----------  ----------  ----------  ---------   ----------- ----------  -----------
P1          Mr. Smith   New York    C1          Jane        S1          Harvard     CRS1        Math
P1          Mr. Smith   New York    C2          John        S2          Princeton   CRS2        Science      */

Regarding your "result you are hoping to see" you should be carefull which table you are selecting FROM and which are the tables that should be LEFT JOINed. For your expected result you should put course table in FROM clause. (I've adjusted the sample data to get null values as in your resultset)
--    M a i n    S Q L :   (Option 2.) 
Select      b.parent_id, b.parent_name, b.location,  
            c.child_id, c.child_name,
            s.school_id, s.school_name, 
            crs.course_id, crs.course_name
From        course crs
Left Join   base b ON( crs.parent_id = b.parent_id )
Left Join   child c ON( c.parent_id = b.parent_id And c.child_id = crs.child_id)
Left Join   school s ON( s.parent_id = c.parent_id And 
                         s.child_id = c.child_id);

/*
PARENT_ID   PARENT_NAME LOCATION    CHILD_ID    CHILD_NAME  SCHOOL_ID   SCHOOL_NAME COURSE_ID   COURSE_NAME
---------   ----------- ----------  ----------  ----------  ---------   ----------- ----------  -----------
P1          Mr. Smith   New York    C1          Jane        S1          Harvard     CRS1        Math
P1          Mr. Smith   New York    C2          John        S2          Princeton   CRS2        Science
P1          Mr. Smith   New York    null        null        null        null        CRS3        Music      */


See the fiddle here.

Exactly, lack of school / child relation: it's quite a strange to see useless parent_id field in the School table while not having shool_id in the Child table (I doubt if we should add child_id within School - Harvard has a lot of students)

@DmitryBychenko There are a few other issues here, but this is the  answer to a specific problem of multiple rows and expected result. Nothing more and nothing less. Regarding number of Harvard students - this is not Harvard students app (no need to list them all) - more likely something related to parents, children, schools and courses for some unknown reporting. Maybe that's why the base table starts with parent_id.

Yes, it's doing a cross join between CHILD and SCHOOL.

@d r thanks so much for your input. Unfortunately, there is no relationship between the course, child and school tables. All they have is the parent_id from the base table.
Also in some cases, parent_id(P2) might have more records for child  and less for school and child.
My goal is to join child,school and courses to the main base table

@SenyoAborgah Sorry, but you should realy explain what you want. There is no course table at all, yet the courses are in your expected result. How to say which child is in which school? More specific, in your result who and how put Jane in Harvard and John in Princeton? Too many unclear situations. And what exactly should mean your comment: "Also in some cases, parent_id(P2) might have more records for child and less for school and child."??? . We know nothing about your context, keep that in mind when asking a quesion. Any info missing leads to the waste of time.

@dr thanks. I need to join 6 tables to the main base table. The base table has a primary key called parent_id.  The 6 other tables don't have any relationship between them only the parent_id linking all 6 tables back to the main base table.
I added the course table just to show that if there are 3 records in the courses table with the same primary id as child and school we will see it as I have it. child and school has 2 records each in their respective table.
My client wants to download one excel sheet with all these 6 tables joining to the main base table.

@SenyoAborgah Without propper links between tables you will not be able to avoid multiplicated rows. If child and school have 2 records each then the result is 4 rows for 1 parent because each child would be joined to each school ( 2 x 2 = 4 ), just as it is in your sql above. John And Jane are joined to both schools. The result that you expected is unreachable without the link between child and school.
